# Is there a way to make an .exe file automatically start when a Windows 10 PC is booted/started, only in the CMD/Terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I’m a bit confused as to what you mean.

I built a python package and it's working fine. After that, I converted the python package from .py to .exe file and the .exe file also working fine.

But after I add .exe file to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` this path. After the .exe file run when the windows system is restarted it raises the file not found error.
If I run the .exe file manually in a startup it works fine and it takes a path as `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` but after restarting the windows system it takes path `C:\Windows\System32\`.

Is there any other way to run the file automatically when the windows system is restarted or switch on?

Comment: It looks more like problem with your python code and how it looks for some specific file - i.e. it looks like it depends on specific current working directory (CWD)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the registry to run files on startup, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run can be used, MAKE SURE YOU ARE CAREFUL when adding and removing values within the registry however.

I'm not sure why the startup folder is not working for you however, I'm pretty sure buran is correct in his possible answer